# How to disable buffering in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Some process in PHP sends messages while it goes.

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
      echo "message $i<br>";
      sleep(3);
    }
```

But user doesn't see any message until this process ends.
Output buffering in PHP disabled. 
I'm a client of web-hosting with Apache-server. 
How to prevent output buffering in .htaccess?

In PHP

1. `ini_set('output_buffering', 0);`  - no effect
2. `ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');` - no effect
3. `while(ob_end_flush());   flush();`  - no effect
4. `ob_implicit_flush(true);  ob_end_clean();` - no effect

In .htaccess

1. `php_flag output_buffering off`  - no effect
2. `php_value implicit_flush on` - no effect

Works only:

```
 echo str_repeat(' ', 32768);
```

but it's terrible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent output buffering with PHP and Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028587/prevent-output-buffering-with-php-and-apache)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. It's more accurate question. But no answer yet.

Comment: Problem was with nginx.
It works: header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');